# Giving Multiple Authors Access to a Plugin's WP.org Repo

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

A plugin I've released has a collaborator.  So I put them into the readme.txt file and they show up on the plugin page and all that.

Does doing this automagically give them access to the SVN repository for the plugin?  Or is there some other process to go through to get them access?  Or is only one user allowed per repo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As long as you use a valid WordPress.org username in the `Contributors:` tag in `readme.txt`, then yes: once the `readme.txt` is parsed by Extend/SVN, then the specified username *automagically* has SVN-commit access to the Plugin.

Note: I know that it works for the **`Contribuors:`** tag, as I am such a contributor on a couple Plugins. If you're using a **`Collaborators:`** tag, I am unsure of how such a tag gets parsed.

### EDIT

And I mis-spoke somewhat. @Otto reminds me that committers must also be added, via the `plugins\plugin-name\advanced` page. So, props Otto; I had completely forgotten about that part!

So, there's really no *automagic*. Go to `wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-name/advanced`, look for the **Committers** heading, add a WPORG username to the text field, and click "Add Committer".

Comment: Whoops; had to revise my answer. Please see the edit.

Comment: Update: This has been moved to https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-name/advanced/